# Question about "Infinite Group with all subgroups having finite index"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

*Since my reputation is not enough to comment on the [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4667279/infinite-group-with-all-subgroups-having-finite-index), I have to post a question here, I will sincerely apologize if this behavior is not appropriate.*

In the comments and the answer, [@Derek Holt](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2820/derek-holt) said that $|G:H|=2$ follows from the fact the automorphism group of an infinite cyclic group has order 2
, and for $y \in G\setminus H$, $y^{-1}xy = x^{-1}$, but I still cannot understand it.

I know that if $H$ is normal in $G$ then there is a homomorphism from $G$ to $Aut(H)$, hence $|G:H| \leq 2$, but how to prove that $H$ is normal? Or there is a way to show this without using normality?

Comment: [A subgroup of index 2 is always normal.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/84632/742)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I know this, but my central question is that I cannot understand how to know $H$ is of index $2$, and I think that he deduces this from the normality, is there anything wrong with my thoughts?

Comment: I think you have might a point -- I added a comment on Derek's answer. But this question should be closed anyway, in my opinion. Also see the older answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379234/terminology-for-infinite-groups-all-of-whose-subgroup-have-finite-index, which seems to be bullet-proof.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Thank you for your help! I have read the older answer you mentioned, it is really good.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed normality of $H$ in my answer. I will correct it.

Comment: So the issue was addressed by replacing $H$ with its core, and is now solved in the original post. I think this should be closed as a duplicate pointing there. Agreed?